# Multiple threads using same DbContext in Dependency Injection Blazor App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor-server-side

In a .NET Core Blazor Server application, I have an authentication Service which validates user credentials when the user attempts to change their password.

```
01.    protected void btnSavePWD_OnClick()
02.    {
03.        try
04.        {
05.            SignOnService.Login(SessionSvc.CurrentUser.Username, this.OriginalPassword); // <-- validates credentials before updating password
06.    
07.                if (!UpdatePassword(this.NewPassword))
08.                {
09.                    ...
10.                }
11.            }
12.        }
13.    }
14.
15.    private Boolean UpdatePassword(String newPWD)
16.    {
17.
18.        Int64 signOnID      = SessionSvc.CurrentUser.ID;
19.        String authorName   = SessionSvc.CurrentUser.Username;
20.
21.        return SignOnService.ChangePassword(signOnID, newPWD, newPWD, authorName);  // <-- Updates password
22.    }
```

You can see on line 05 that a call is made to the `SignOnService` to validate the user credentials. The same service is called again on line 21 to actually change the password.

The Login method of the `SignOnService` looks like ...

```
01. public SingleSignOn Login(String username, String password, String appCode = null)
02. {
03.    
04.     // Get the SingleSignOnRecord
05.     //
06.     SingleSignOn singleSignOn = this.singleSignOnRepository.GetSingleSignOnByCredentials(username, password);
07.     Boolean loginWasSuccessful = (singleSignOn != null);
08.    
09.     // log a successful login event in the history table and reset the failed log attempts 
10.     // in the SINGLE_SIGN_ON record. Do not await the results. If it breaks, we still want 
11.     // the user to be able to use the application.
12.     //
13.     this.singleSignOnRepository.UpdateFailedLoginForUsernameAsync(username, loginWasSuccessful); // don't wait for it to return
14.     this.singleSignOnRepository.CreateSignOnHistoryEntryAsync(singleSignOn, singleSignOn.Username);    // don't wait for it to return
    
15.     return singleSignOn;
16. }
```

Perhaps you have noticed the start of the problem in the comments in lines 09 - 12. I want to log a record entry but don't want to await the results. It's not important enough to affect the user's experience if either fail or take a long time to complete. The problem is that it uses the same `DBContext` that the `ChangePassword` method needs to use. Since we don't wait for the context to be freed up, it means that it is not available for the `ChangePassword` method when it's called.

The question is ... using Dependency Injection and the DI Container provided in .NET CORE ... how do I provide a new `DBContext` to the `ChangePassword` method without creating a concrete instance and passing it in as a parameter to the method. It seems that I would need a new instance of the Service, but my Service is already scoped as Transient in the Startup.cs.

```
services.AddDbContext<UniqueDBCtx>(options =>
{
    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ThriftDB"));
});
services.AddTransient<ISingleSignOnService, SingleSignOnService>();
services.AddTransient<ISingleSignOnRepository, SingleSignOnRepository>();
```

Comment: You're using `DbContext` incorrectly and you **absolutely must** use `await` with your Async-methods.

Comment: "how do I provide a new DBContext to the ChangePassword method without creating a concrete instance and passing it in as a parameter to the method." - **why** don't you want to pass it as a parameter?

Comment: ...are you using the repository-anti-pattern? If so, that's another thing you're doing wrong. **Do not use the repository anti-pattern with DbContext**.

Comment: the only purpose of trying to execute concurrent operations on a `DbContext` is for performance. But looks like it's not your purpose. That means we can have a work around. For a general solution (supporting a dynamic number of DbContext instances), instead of injecting a `DbContext`, you need some `DbContext` factory. Otherwise, you need to explicitly register each DbContext (maybe with different type or name) and consume those specific ones in your services.

Comment: @KingKing Unless something has changed in the past few months `DbContext` does not support concurrent operations - so each-and-every `IQueryable<T>.ToListAsync` and `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` must be `await`ed before the next operation can start. The only way to have concurrent DB operations with EF/EFCore is by creating multiple `DbContext` instances. Of course DBs tend to be IO-bound, not CPU-bound, so the performance benefits of running queries concurrently are probably not as great as you'd expect.

Comment: @Dai I do know about that, if you read my comment carefully (from `.For a general solution ...`), I already talked about creating multiple instances of DbContext. That's when the user wants to go his way, and I doubt that he can work-around to not have to execute multiple async operations (because he may not want to boost the performance at all, not mentioned in his question).

Comment: @KingKing Yes, but you wrote "the only purpose of trying to execute concurrent operations on a DbContext is for performance" - but the thing is _that will *never* work_ because `DbContext` doesn't support concurrency.

Comment: @Dai the app (running the queries) don't care about the DB server, as long as the server can handle the requests, and the number of clients is not large, I believe that async operations may improve the performance a bit (from the client's point of view) by reducing the request processing time. Of course that would be like multiply the number of physical clients, so instead of 10 clients, the actual requests count may be 100 which will really put a burden on the DB server. But as long as the server can handle it, the experience may be good.

Comment: @Dai that's the point of user's view. Developer who don't know about the concurrency support will ***wish*** for that feature, that's his purpose.

Comment: i would recomment to use IDbContextFactory to make sure to only have a very short live-time. Otherwise, as already explained, you will run into massive concurrency problems